# onClick event in Dart Web

Tags: html, dart, dart-html

I am a beginner to Dart-Web. I tried to handle click events in the HTML DOM via dart, but it doesn't seem to work. Below it my current code.

```
<div>
   <button type="button" onclick="(onclick)=clickHandle()">Sign-in</button>
</div>


@Component(
 selector: 'todo-list',
 styleUrls: ['login_component.css'],
 templateUrl: 'login_component.html',
 directives: [
  MaterialButtonComponent,
  MaterialCheckboxComponent,
  MaterialFabComponent,
  MaterialIconComponent,
  materialInputDirectives,
  materialInputDirectives,
  NgFor,
  NgIf,
 ],
 providers: [ClassProvider(LoginService)],
 )
 class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  final LoginService loginService;

  List<String> items = [];
  String newTodo = '';

  LoginComponent(this.loginService);

  @override
  Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {
  items = await loginService.getTodoList();
  }

  void add() {
  items.add(newTodo);
  newTodo = '';
  }

  void clickHandle() {
  print("Button Clicked");
  }

  String remove(int index) => items.removeAt(index);
  }
```

Please do request any additional files that are needed to answer the question.

Comment: Is this angular dart? Because if it is so then youre calling your function on click incorrectly

Comment: no its simple html and its dart file

Comment: well that's odd, the structure seems strangely similar to angular dart, please tell which framework is this part of , or the tutorial you followed that resulted in this code.

Answer (score 2):

```
onclick="(onclick)=clickHandle()"
```

is wrong.

It should be

```
(click)="clickHandle()"
```

The event is `click`, `onClick` is just a property where you can register a handler function to be called when that `click` event happens, but Angular is registering the handler in `onClick` for you.